# can we use leaflet 1 beta for vector tiles without mapbox GL?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl

I am still learning more about leaflet 1. I went through the change log saw a lot of improvement was done for vector.
Does leaflet 1 have it's own way for vector tiles without using Mapbox GL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet can't do that out-of-the-box but you could use the vectortile plugin:

> A Leaflet Plugin that renders Mapbox Vector Tiles on HTML5 Canvas. Though there is extensive use of MapboxVectorTiles in Mapnik PNG tile rendering as well as MapboxGL, there is a strange lacking of libraries that integrate these vector tiles directly into Leaflet. Search no more, the library you have been looking for is here!

https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile